# Very ironic and ridiculous

Tags: discussion

I'm blocked for making questions , because someone think that my previous questions were BAD.
But my reputation is increased because my previous questions are taking up-votes.
Well , i think it's better or to unblock me for making questions , or you should block that my questions receive up votes , because the case is becoming very ironic and ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

Its automatic. If enough people think your questions are good, the question ban will also automatically be lifted.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/135565 read that. It's a network wide thing.

Comment: The comments are essentially down to arguements over whether the question ban is fair. Its been discussed in detail. The reasoning for why its secret is here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161534/how-many-downvotes-do-you-have-to-get-to-be-banned-from-questioning-answering/161536#161536 . As far as I'm concerned, this comment thread isn't really serving much purpose, outside, well, arguement. These is what is, yes, the exact criteria is secret, and no, no one will lift the question ban. That's all there is.

Comment: My messages cannot be viewed anymore. POWERFUL CENSORSHIP !!!!  And it's ridiculous because the remaining comments now have no sense without my comments ???!!!!!